# Turn off Bing chat bot on Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, chat, bing

How do I turn off this annoying chat bot which opens up every time on Bing (on Microsoft Edge)?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's one reason I don't use Bing…

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got it. Go to Bing.com then go to Settings > More and then Disable from there.

## Settings

[image]

## Uncheck "Show Bing Chat"

[image]

I was earlier trying in Microsoft Edge settings instead of Bing settings.